# Add an Image Map to a rotating image

Tags: html, css, imagemap, rotatetransform

So I currently have an image that is rotating 360degs in an infinite loop. It has 8 different products in the image and instead of linking the entire image itself to one page, I was wondering if there was a way I could image map each product separately while the image still rotates 360degs.

I'm currently using a simple CSS3 image rotate as seen below:

```
.animation
{
    -webkit-animation:spin 18s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 18s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 18s linear infinite;        
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Anyone ever seen this implemented before?

Answer (score 0):

This is really tough problem. I would not personally use image maps in that case, but some clickable divs with `opacity:0` on your image.

If you do so, you can rotate them with your image, but changing [transform-origin](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp) property, so the point of rotation would be the same.

Comment: I just thought about this a lot, wouldn't the image maps stay with each product in the image? Especially since the image itself is rotating, but the coordinates are still saying the same on the image? Does that make sense?